# Simple Codeigniter Site hanging (8min+) - where to profile/benchmark?

Tags: codeigniter, profiling, benchmarking, profiler

My CI site will sometimes just hang - server seems to take forever to answer my request, i.e. when just loading the homepage, and other pages too. It's quite random and only does it sometimes.

I turned on profiling and hit the homepage, this was the result:

[image]

Here's the **home/index method**

```
function index()
{ 
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);  

$this->benchmark->mark('template_sets_start');
   $this->template->title('Yay, welcome to my site');  
   $this->template->js('home.js,cycle.js');             
$this->benchmark->mark('template_set_end');

$this->benchmark->mark('template_load_start');
   $this->template->load('template/home'); 
$this->benchmark->mark('template_load_end');
}  
}
```

Since the time returned for the template stuff is low, I can assume the lag isn't happening anywhere in the views.

An ideas or suggestions?

===EDIT===

One thing I found is the config is setting the base_url dynamically. Code below, could this potentially cause slow-dows?

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: Is this on a live server or locally? Have you tested on different servers?

Comment: Is there any other controller is running? if it is can you show the coding?

Comment: No other controllers running. Site is on local machine but MySQL is on server - I've put the site on the same server as the MySQL to see if that made a difference but encountered similar lags. The annoying thing is that it's not consistent!. Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted is almost definitely not the issue. I've had something similar happen though, try ***not*** using the db for sessions and see if that helps.

Comment: @Wesley, ok thanks, will try that and see if it happens again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution time for "Template Sets" is 0.0000, because you missed "s" in mark's name.

Change:

```
$this->benchmark->mark('template_set_end');
```

to

```
$this->benchmark->mark('template_sets_end');
```

Comment: Nice catch, although this is likely only one facet of the benchmarking issue.